# Android Studio: Explicitly revoke camera permission

Tags: android, android-permissions

I'm updating an app that doesn't need to use the camera or to record audio. I've removed the permissions from the manifest but the upload fails with

> Your APK or Android App Bundle is using permissions that require a
> privacy policy: (android.permission.CAMERA,
> android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO).

I can see in generated manifests that the permissions get "injected".

This hasn't worked:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" tools:node="remove"/>
```

How do I stop that, or how do I tell the app that I will never, ever, ever want to use the camera?

Comment: You should remove camera permission from the manifest. Also, check your code if you take runtime camera permission from anywhere remove it also.

Comment: @NayanSarder I've got it out of my manifest. I've just had to rebuild the app after failing miserably at removing some lines from "import"